# Three Layer Application using maven multimodule

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, maven-module

I need to ask the experiment people around the java technologies.
I develop a 3-tiers application :

Presentation Layer: for the User Interface.
Service Layer: for the business Logic.
Data Layer: for accessing to the database.

Please is this feasible with maven multi-module , for example a module for the User Interface layer and module for the service layer and module for data layer.

If is feasible , Please how proceed ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes its feasible and since you know the term multimodule its very easier to search for it over the net.

Comment: could you please suggest tuto or application like munchened ?

Comment: Best Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49562268/create-three-tier-application-presentation-business-dataaccess-with-common